# Корректно ли составлено предложение? (1)

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, верно ли составлено предложение: "С выражением скуки и столовой утварью в руках они молча сидели у огня, и даже не шелохнулись и головы не подняли при моём появлении."? Мне почему-то кажется, что две его части не согласуются друг с другом. Так ли это? Я - автор, и переписывать не хочу, если оно составлено корректно.
Спасибо.

Comment: Здесь всё согласуется, об этом не беспокойтесь.. Сложность - в ряде однородных(?) сказуемых. Я понимаю, чем вы руководствовались, ставя запятую после "огня". Но нужна ли она на самом деле? Вот не знаю. Хотелось бы именно на этот вопрос услышать ответ от местных "авторитетеов".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*С выражением скуки **на лице** и столовой утварью в руках они молча сидели у огня, и даже не шелохнулись и головы не подняли при моём появлении.*

1. Такие сочетания встречаются в литературе, но это **специальный художественный прием.** Здесь использованы неоднородные понятия "утварь" и "выражение скуки".

Розенталь http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm

1. Ошибочным является соединение в нейтральном стиле речи **в качестве однородных членов несопоставимых (вещественно неоднородных) понятий,** например: покраснел от смущения и от быстрой ходьбы; в сравнении с вечностью и Монбланом.

Подобные сочетания используются в художественной литературе **как специальный стилистический прием** (создание **комического** эффекта, **индивидуализация речи** рассказчика или персонажа **и т.д.)**, например:
В продолжение ночи он раза три чуть не убил меня то страхом, то ногами (Герцен); ...На подъезд выбежали девки и лакеи со свечами и радостными лицами (Л. Толстой); Лев Саввич Турманов, дюжинный обыватель, имеющий капиталец, молодую жену и солидную плешь, как-то играл на именинах у приятеля в винт (Чехов).

2. Что касается **ЗАПЯТОЙ**, то она **факультативная** (авторская), ее можно и не ставить, а можно поставить.

Запятая допускается в данном случае, так как однородные сказуемые значительно распространены. Вторая фраза имеет явно присоединительный характер, поэтому союз И можно считать присоединительным (его можно заменить союзом ПРИЧЕМ). В этом случае перед союзом И делается **подчеркнутая пауза.** В этом будет ваше **авторское решение.**

**При отсутствии запятой и паузы** повторяющихся союзов И тоже не будет, так как они имеют **разные функции**. Второй союз И соединяет близкие по смыслу и по грамматике понятия, а первый союз И присоединяет эту пару (схема 1 + 2). Таким образом, этот вариант **соответствует правилам.**

Примечание. Повторяющийся союз И...И соответсвует перечислительной интонации, но такой интонации здесь нет.

Теория: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом и, образуют тесно связанную **по смыслу пару**, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится: **Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам** (Л. Т.) — парная группа сбегала и сохла с общим второстепенным членом по канавам, оба глагола несовершенного вида, в отличие от глагола-сказуемого совершенного вида сбыла; Задолго до рассвета Ильинична затопила печь и к утру уже выпекла хлеб и насушила две сумы сухарей (Ш.) — парная группа выпекла и насушила с общим обстоятельством времени к утру;

Comment: А какие, простите, у автора сочетания "несопоставимы"?!

Comment: *Что касается запятой, то она допускается в данном случае* - простите, если считать все три сказуемых однородными, то запятая не "допускается", а просто необходима в силу повторяющегося союза.

Comment: "Несопоставимы" вещественно неоднородные  (по Розенталю) "выражение скуки" и "столовые приборы". Моя личая претензия к _стилю_ здесь: автору следовало бы повторить предлог ("со"), а "выражение" явным образом  отправить к _лицу_ ("на лице"), чтобы в читательском восприятии оно не липло к "рукам" (жестами можно многое "выразить").

Comment: 1. Я только цитирую текст Розенталя,но ничего не говорила о несовместимости в приведенном примере. (2) Здесь нет повторяющихся союзов, два союза И  имеют разную функцию. Первый союз И присоединительный,  второй союз И соединяет два однородных сказуемых, близких по смыслу.

Comment: @Alex_ander - *"Несопоставимы" вещественно неоднородные (по Розенталю) "выражение скуки" и "столовые приборы"*. Это спорный вопрос... Контекст нужен, я так очень даже представил эту компанию с вилками в руках за скучным обедом. Но автор вообше не об этом спрашивает... У него "две части", а в двух частях однородными могут быть только сказуемуе - хотя и это обсуждаемо.

Comment: *Я только цитирую текст Розенталя,но ничего не говорила о несовместимости в приведенном примере.* - А, простите, я думал, вы на вопрос отвечаете, а вы о чес-то о своем...

Comment: Розенталь относит "вечность" и "Монблан" к разнородным сущностям (абстрактная и реальная), здесь - то же самое.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Я бы написала так: С выражением скуки на лице  и столовой утварью в руках. С вашим мнением о разнородных сущностях согласна, поэтому здесь именно стилистический прием.

Comment: Alex_ander  *здесь - то же самое* - это лично ваша интерпретация. Я не вижу здесь "то же самого".  Но у автора вообще нет вопроса об этом. т

Comment: Даже одно из моих пожеланий (при осуществлении) улучшает фразу, иначе общий предлог ведет и к общим "рукам".

Comment: @ behemotus Выражение чего-то (видимая реакция на что-то) и физические предметы вроде столовых приборов - чем не разнородные сущности?

Comment: @Alex_ander - я все, что имел сказать, вынес в свой ответ.

Comment: @Alex_ander *чем не разнородные сущности?* - вы задаете философский вопрос, а философия (любая причем, не только материалистическая) предполагает, что говорить о том, в чем сущности разнятся, можно лишь после того, как мы выявили, что в них общего. Говоря по-простому, это нужен контекст. В контексте моего виртуального мира эти сущности могут быть вполне однородны. Скучный званый обед, присутствующие сидят с вилками в руках - и не знаю, чем еще занять руки. Вот вам и однородность в плане выражения скуки.

Comment: @Alex_ander (продолжение) Здесь нет комического эффекта, во всяком случае того, о котором вы и Sharon толковать изволите.

Answer (score 0):

Не хотел отвечать, ибо в общем-то не о чем. Но придется, видимо.

> Мне почему-то кажется, что две его части не согласуются друг с другом.

Не вижу ни малейшего повода говорить о какой-то "несогласованности". Разумеется,  "согласованность" я понимаю как синтаксическую категорию, говорить о каких-то логических нестыковках невозможно. Я, впрочем, понял, что имеют в виду два моих оппонента, настаивающие на какой-то "вещественной неоднородности". Они видят "в руках" относящимся не только к "утвари", но и к "выражению скуки". Кабы так, то да, стилистический ляп имел бы место. Но я такого не предполагаю изначально. Хотя, повторюсь, автор не об этом спрашивает.

@Alex_ander

> Даже одно из моих пожеланий (при осуществлении) улучшает фразу, иначе
> общий предлог ведет и к общим "рукам"

Могу согласиться с тем, что фраза хужже не станет. Но про "улучшение" я бы не говорил

/===

Теперь о запятой после "огня". Вот с ней - сложнее. Опускаю вводную, вопрос понятен.

@Sharon

> Здесь нет повторяющихся союзов, два союза И имеют разную функцию.
> Первый союз И присоединительный, второй союз И соединяет два
> однородных сказуемых, близких по смыслу.

Это хорошая идея, логика мне понятна, и мне нравится формулировка (я всегда испытывал затруднения, подбирая термин для таких "многоуровневых" союзах, но вот беда, в таком виде - это всего лишь субъективное мнение. Во-первых, не ясно, из чего исходил автор (я-то предполагаю, что запятая поставлена как раз по мотиву повторяющихся союзов, автор даже не оговаривает  эту особенность, ему этот вопрос очевиден. И во-вторых, нигде, от Правил-56 до Розенталя, нет даже упоминания о каких-то "разнофункциональных" союзах, маскирующихся под повторяющиеся. По крайней мере - я не помню такого. Судя по всему, этот случай даже не рассматривается в пособиях. То есть объяснять надо как-то по-другому. Особенно настораживает то, что достаточно убрать слово "даже" - и союз становится вполне себе повторяющимся. На этом основании вывод о какой-то "разной функциональности" союзов выглядит весьма спорным.

Я реально не знаю, чем можно обосновать такой, желаемый мной, вариант пунктуации, но очень хочу видеть фразу без запятой.

(+)===
Увидел только что

> > Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом и, образуют
> > тесно связанную по смыслу пару,

> (Розенталь)

Да, это уже лучше, ни о каких разных функция не говорится. Вопрос только в том, захочет ли автор применить это правило - или он будет настаивать именно на повторяющихся союзах. Я не берусь его переубеждать только на основании цитаты из Розенталя. Тут важно понимание авторского понимания, простите за каламбур.